# Save Press This Posts in a Custom Post Type Wordpress 5.3

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, bookmarks

I'm wondering, is there a way to modify the "Press This" bookmarklet so that posts are saved to a custom post type instead of to a post.

Comment: you can use the filter `press_this_save_post` https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/press-this/tags/1.1.1/class-wp-press-this-plugin.php#L149

Comment: Hope you find what you need in this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192059/save-press-this-posts-in-a-custom-post-type